# R reactable - get a newline in a text column

Tags: r, reactable

How do I make reactable display a newline in a text column?

This does not work:

```
library(reactable)

reactable(
  data.frame(text = "test, \n test, \n test")
)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `<br>` instead of `\n` and set  `colDef(html = TRUE)`.

```
library(reactable)

reactable(
  data.frame(text = "test, <br> test, <br> test"),
  columns = list(text = colDef(html = TRUE))
)
```

If needed uses `gsub` to change the extisting `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(text = "test, \n test, \n test")
df$text <- gsub("\\n", "<br>", df$text)
```